# Angular: set as startup a different project

Tags: angular, startup

As I am new, I am experimenting with different Angular projects in order to learn.

In VS code I have a main folder,
MainFolder : my-first-app.
So far, by pressing `ngServe` I was running the my-first-app page.
I then added a
SecondaryFolder: my-second-app
in the MainFolder, which includes an Angular project.

I wanted the my-second-app to run as default when I press `ngServe`.
I thought that this will be succeeded by changing the angular.json file from

```
"defaultProject": "my-first-app"
```

to

```
"defaultProject": "my-secondary-app"
```

That didn't do the trick.
Could someone let me know how I set as startup another project in the described Folder structure?

Comment: I think you might be looking for something amongst [the lines of having multiple applications serving one main application](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527)

Answer (score 2):

If I understant it correctly, you have 2 separate applications.
So, you have to just change the path in terminal.

```
cd..
cd .\my-secondary-app\
```